# getting error wrong month in Date while using Spring Rest Service

Tags: json, spring, spring-restcontroller

I am using spring rest services. I am getting wrong month when the json is parsed by Spring

> to :    Fri Jan 13 05:30:00 IST 2017
>   from :  Sat Jan 14 05:30:00 IST 2017

I am not even passing the time also time is not as my system clock.

This is my json request

```
{"emp_name":"Pavan Keely","emp_id":"135835","entry_by":"172033","is_half_day":false,"applied_to_date":"13/02/2017","applied_from_date":"14/02/2017","taken_to_date":"","taken_from_date":"","leave_type_id":"1"}
```

This is POJO class

```
public class AppliedLeave
{

private int id;
private String emp_id;
private int leave_type_id;
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date applied_from_date;
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date applied_to_date;
private boolean is_half_day;
private double no_of_days_applied;
private String entry_by;
private String entry_date;
}
```

Assume getter setter are there

And this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-taken-leave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> addTakenLeave(@RequestBody TakenLeave takenLeave)
{
    if ((leaveTrackerService.addTakenLeave(takenLeave)).equals("success"))
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"success\": \"true\" }",        HttpStatus.OK);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"success\": \"false\" }", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")` instead.